# Persist entity using Java Hibernate API and update if already exists

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Have the following table and Java Entity:

```
CREATE TABLE search_terms (
id int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
term varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
last_search_date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
search_count int(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
user_email varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


public class SearchTerms implements Serializable {
private Long id;
private String term;
private Timestamp lastSearchDate;
private int searchCount;
private String userEmail;
```

Want to persist java objects of the given type into the table above.

Example:

```
List<String> searchTerms = Arrays.asList("test1", "test2", "test3");
saveSearchParams(searchTerms);
```

If any of those terms exist in the table, I want to increment searchCount else save as a new row.

Need to use JPA.em().merge(o) etc and not have sql insert/update queries

Added the following constant on the two columns but JPA.em().merge(o) keeps inserting new rows.

```
@Table(name="search_terms",  uniqueConstraints= { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"term", "user_email"})})
```

```
saveSearchParams() {
        searchTerms.forEach(o -> {
            SearchTerms term = new SearchTerms();
            term.setSearchCount(1);
            term.setTerm((String) o);
            term.setUserEmail(email);
            jpaApi.em().merge(term);
        });
}
```

[image]

Any help on or documentation is appreciated.

Comment: Did you set the @Id annotation properly on your primary key field in your entity. For merge() to identify new (transient state) instances vs detached instances, that key is important.

Answer (score 0):

Merge can both update and insert, but you should check if the object exists in DB to see if you have to set the counter to one or add one to it, for this you will have to throw a query for each element.

try this:

```
saveSearchParams() {
    searchTerms.forEach(o -> {
        //search for example by id or in any other way
        SearchTerms term = jpaApi.em().find(SearchTerms.class, o.getId());
        if (term == null){
            term = new SearchTerms();
            term.setSearchCount(1);
        }else{
            term.setSearchCount(term.getSearchCount()+1);
        }
        
        term.setTerm((String) o);
        term.setUserEmail(email);
        jpaApi.em().merge(term);
    });
}
```